# Android serialize a PendingIntent

Tags: java, android, serialization

I know that a PendingIntent doesn't implement the Serielizeable interface. But if I create a POJO and add that intent as a member of my object, and letting that POJO implement serializeable, will that work?

This is what I think:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, someClass.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

POJO myPOJO = new POJO();
myPojo.setIntent(pi);
...
```

serialize the POJO etc, as explained above. Will that POJO still be serializeable, and after deserialization, will I be able to fetch the PendingIntent with myPOJO.getIntent(); ?

Sorry if it's obvious. thankful for any help.

Marcus

Comment: why do you need Serializable?  PendingIntent is Parcelable so you should use Parcelable iface

Comment: I need to persist the PendinIntent so that I can use it to cancel an alarm that I've set with alarm manager even after the app was destroyed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if I create a POJO and add that intent as a member of my object, and letting that POJO implement serializeable, will that work?

No.

> will I be able to fetch the PendingIntent with myPOJO.getIntent(); ?

No. A `PendingIntent` cannot survive outside of the running OS.

In this case, assuming that your code snippet resembles your actual use case, you do not need to persist the `PendingIntent`; instead, persist the things that allow you to make a new `PendingIntent` later on.

Comment: I need to persist the pending intent so I can use it with AlarmManager to cancel an alarm, after my app is destroyed (I have my alarms in a arraylist which isn't storeable in shared prefs.) But all I need to persist from the Pending Intent is the requestCode (which in my case is the time in millliseconds when the alarm was set). So, I could just persist the requestCode in my POJO (alarm), right?

Comment: Also, are you the real Mark Murphy?

Comment: @Marcus: "So, I could just persist the requestCode in my POJO (alarm), right?" -- correct. Then you recreate the `PendingIntent` as needed later on. "are you the real Mark Murphy?" -- my name is Mark Murphy. However, there are lots of Mark Murphys in the world. Also, whether or not I am real is up for debate. :-)

Comment: Already the fact that he answered your question gives an indication that he is real. The fact that he answered your question about reality should give you 100% assurance that he is real.